# How to render a tilemap efficiently?

Tags: java, rendering, tiles, libgdx

I'm using this code to load a tiled map, composed of 1000x1000 32x32px tiles:

```
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("levels/xyz.tmx");

camera = new OrthographicCamera();

camera.setToOrtho(false, Constants.WORLD_WINDOW_SIZE.x / 32,
            Constants.WORLD_WINDOW_SIZE.y / 32);

renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / 32f);

renderer.getSpriteBatch().disableBlending();

renderer.setView(camera);
```

And this code for rendering:

```
camera.update();
renderer.setView(camera);   
renderer.render();
```

However, I have huge performance issues. How can I optimize this code ? Will splitting the map in multiple submaps help?

Greetings, TM3P

Comment: You should consider rendering only the visible tiles/objects. related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48548/how-to-draw-only-visible-tiles  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984389/opengl-selective-world-rendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the techniques discussed in the [link above](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48548/how-to-draw-only-visible-tiles), think about frame layering as well. In my game engine (board is 750 x 450 hexes of 32^2 pixels) I triple buffer the display into map, units, and highlights. On each Paint cycle:

- MapBuffer is repainted only if the view has panned or zoomed;
- UnitBuffer is refreshed from MapBuffer and units repainted only if one or more units has moved;
- HighlightBuffer is refreshed from UnitBuffer and repainted; and
- HighightBuffer is drawn to screen.

Comment: Thanks, that's a technique I've never thought of. I'll code something similar some day

Comment: I was initially intimidated when I realized it was necessary - but it turned out to be quite straightforward. P.S.: The best and most appreciated thank you is a vote.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't vote up, nor down :|

Comment: Well, nice one. I got to GameDev after a few years of programming (I'm a professional WebDev), today I got my first big problem with my game, I just noticed that on mobile devices my game is running slow when I render a bigger scene (players can pick the size). :D