# How do I stop off-screen tiles of a 2D tilemap from being rendered?

Tags: java, rendering, tilemap, optimization, slick

I am seeing lag because I render all tiles in my map at once.  How can I exclude off-screen tiles from being rendered?

My tiles are 32×32 and my player is always in the centre of the screen.

Here is my render method:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("assets/maps/"+map+".json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

for(int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < blocksHeight; y++) {
        Object out = jsonObject.get("x"+x+"y"+y);
        String f = out.toString();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(f);                
        g.drawImage(GetImage.ReturnImage(i), x*Size.Tile, y*Size.Tile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw only visible tiles?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48548/how-to-draw-only-visible-tiles)

Comment: no his is a 3d plane mine is 2d

Comment: Don't worry i managed to get it working with this:  if (x > (InGame.playerX/32) - 17 && x < (InGame.playerX/32)+18 && y > (InGame.playerY/32) - 5 && y < (InGame.playerY/32)+15) {
        g.drawImage(GetImage.ReturnImage(i), x*Size.Tile, y*Size.Tile);
    }

Comment: maybe instead of redoing the post you could have helped??

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is by testing to see if the tile is outside the screen

```
int screenWidth = [GET_THE_SCREEN_WIDTH];
int screenHeight = [GET_THE_SCREEN_HEIGHT];
for(int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < blocksHeight; y++) {
        Object out = jsonObject.get("x"+x+"y"+y);
        String f = out.toString();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(f);
        if(!x*Size.Tile>screenWidth && !(x-1)*Size.Tile < 0){
            if(!y*Size.Tile>screenHeight && !(y-1)*Size.Tile < 0){
                g.drawImage(GetImage.ReturnImage(i), x*Size.Tile, y*Size.Tile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is how I would do it. And, yes, I have tested it. It works perfectly. You will need to replace '[GET_THE_SCREEN_WIDTH]' and '[GET_THE_SCREEN_HEIGHT]' with a real variable, obviously.

Hope this has helped you